# Libgdx compilation error

Tags: libgdx

I installed libgdx to my IDEA as it written here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx

no visible errors in project, but when I am trying to compile it gives me an error:

```
Error:Android Dex: [android] Unable to execute DX 
Error:Android Dex: [android] com.android.dex.DexException: Cannot merge new index 68094 into a non-jumbo instruction!
```

Also I googled that it can be due small amount of heap size. Then I increased it in Settings->Compilers->Android compilers to 3000, but it didn't help

Comment: LibGDX is OpenGL ES 2.0 only now, so not likely to work great with the emulator anyway. I'd recommend using something like Genymotion if you aren't testing on a physical device.

Comment: No, I am using my phone for my testing. But why you are writing about emulator? this error causes on compilation step, before I choose device.

Answer (score 0):

1) in Intellij IDEA I checked flag "Force jumbo mode" in Setting->Compiler->Android compilers

2) wrote `dex.force.jumbo=true` in project.properties file, which is under android folder